# Why the IP address on 2 machines on the same router having different subnet?

Tags: networking

I have 2 machine. One's IP is 169.254.41.172 and the other is 169.254.72.175. They are both connected to the same router. Why is the 'subnet?' different? I'm referring to the 3rd number between 41 and 72.

Comment: Take a look at http://ask-leo.com/why_cant_i_connect_with_a_169254xx_ip_address.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router is not acting as a DHCP server it seems.
169.254 is a special range usually for Windows machines when they can't obtain an IP address automatically.

From: http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/24/169-254-0-0-addresses-explained/

> Occasionally you may encounter a host which has somehow assigned
>   itself an IP address in the 169.254.0.0/16 range. This is a
>   particularly common symptom of Windows machines which have been
>   configured for DHCP but for whatever reason are unable to contact a
>   DHCP server. When a host fails to dynamically acquire an address, it
>   can optionally assign itself a link-local IPv4 address in accordance
>   with RFC 3927. Microsoft's term for this is Automatic Private Internet
>   Protocol Addressing (APIPA).

Answer (score 4):

These are linklocal addresses, they use 255.255.0.0 as subnet mask, so both addresses are in the same subnet.

These addresses are generated automatically, if you want more control over them you will either need a DHCP server, or configure static IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

These machines are not getting an IP address. The beginning octets of "169.254" identify these addresses as "link-local".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address

For what it's worth, the addresses are not on different subnets as the full link-local definition is 169.254.0.0/16, or a "Class B" subnet. That being said though, there's no way you'll be getting these computers to communicate any time soon. Is the router powered on, are the cables connected and are there uplink lights on the actual RJ45 jacks on both the router and computers? Is DHCP enabled on the router?